Factorization on increments in Markov chain
I'm trying to show the following property for a Markov chain:
$$\left<[x(t+\tau)-x(t)][x(t'+\tau)-x(t')]\right> =\left<x(t+\tau)-x(t)\right>\left<x(t'+\tau)-x(t')\right>  $$
Where $t\neq t'$. The moments are defined by:
$$\left<x(t_1)...x(t_n)\right> = \int dx_1...\int dx_n\, x_1...x_n P_n(x_1,t_1;...;x_n,t_n)$$
And the Markov property is on the conditional probabilities with $t_{i+1}>t_i$:
$$P_{1|n-1}(x_n,t_n|x_{n-1},t_{n-1};...;x_1,t_1) = P_{1|1}(x_n,t_n|x_{n-1},t_{n-1})$$
I have been trying to bring both sides of the equation I need to prove to the same form by introducing new integrals and so on, in various iterations. For example, I had
$$ \int dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 P_4(x_3,t+\tau; x_2, t'+\tau; x_1, t; x_4, t') [x_3x_2-x_1x_2-x_4x_3+x_1x_4]$$
for the left hand side, and
$$ \int dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 P_2(x_3,t+\tau; x_1, t)P_2(x_2, t'+\tau; x_4, t') [x_3x_2-x_1x_2-x_4x_3+x_1x_4]$$
And I don't know how to prove that these are equal either. I feel like I am missing some fundamental property of Markov processes, so any help would be appreciated!

I doubt that the statement you want to prove is generally true for any Markov process.
Note that
\begin{align}
 & \left<x(t+\tau)-x(t)\right>\left<x(t'+\tau)-x(t')\right>  = \\ 
&\left<x(t+\tau)\right>\left<x(t'+\tau)\right>-\left<x(t+\tau)\right>\left<x(t')\right>-\left<x(t)\right>\left<x(t'+\tau)\right>+\left<x(t)\right>\left<x(t')\right>.
\end{align}
Therefore, your statement implies
$$ \left<x(t) \, x(t')\right>=\left<x(t)\right>\left<x(t')\right>, \quad \forall t,t'. $$
Which is not true for any Markov process. Indeed the Markov property doesn't imply the absence of temporal correlations.

I was thinking along the same lines, however I don't think that my statement would imply $\left<x(t)x(t')\right> = \left<x(t)\right>\left<x(t')\right>$. I think it's the combination of all four terms on each side that makes it true.

@SSh2402 I don't think so. If you let $, t'=t$, then it is clear that $\langle \left( x(t+\tau)-x(t) \right)^2 \rangle \neq \langle \left( x(t+\tau)-x(t) \right) \rangle^2$ in general. For a general $t$ and $t'$ you could develop a counter example from any simple process that is Markov and has time correlations, like the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.
